# php hide attributes on casting to array

Tags: php, class, casting, attributes, hide

I coded a php class to represent a query-result. On an incoming query I cast it to an array, convert it to JSON (per json_encode) and return it to the user.

Now I want to define a class intern "debug" attribute, which souldn't be in the output - how can I hide attributes on casting a class to an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare it `private` or `protected`.

```
class Foo
{
   public $bar = 'bar';   
   private $baz = 'baz';
   protected $quux = 'quux';
}

$f = new Foo();

echo json_encode($f);
```

Result:

```
{"bar":"bar"}
```

NB. Requires PHP 5, see [Visibility](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php) in the PHP manual.

Comment: I tried it before - It returns something like "\u0000*\u0000debug":false

Comment: @NaN: As you can see, I just tested it. But don't take my word for it: http://codepad.org/mSCdaBjT

Comment: Okay, I found the error - I casted it to an array... something like  json_encode ((array) $f); doesn't work... weird but true!

Comment: Ah, ok. That *is* weird, but documented behaviour: _"private variables have the class name prepended to the variable name; protected variables have a '*' prepended to the variable name. These prepended values have null bytes on either side.  "_ See: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.casting

Answer (score 2):

Remove the element from the resulting array with `unset`.

Comment: ok, this works quite nice on a few attributes, but I would prefer something without the need of an explicit function call - something like "declaring the attribute as private" (but this doesn't work).